# bollinger bands versus statistics: is 1 standard deviation supposed to be split into two halves by it's mean? or top and bottom bands from mean?

Tags: statistics, pine-script, mean, trading, standard-deviation

I have a question about how bollinger bands are plotted in relation to statistics. In statistics, once a standard deviation is calculated from a mean of a set of numbers, shouldn't interpreting a 1 standard deviation be done so that you divide this number is half, and plot each half above and below the mean? By doing so, you can then determine whether or not it's data points fall within this 1 standard deviation.
Then, correct me if I am wrong, but aren't bollinger bands NOT calculated this way?? Instead, it takes a 1 standard deviation (if you have set it to 1) and plots the WHOLE value both above and below the mean (not splitting in two), thereby doubling the size of this standard-deviation?
Bollinger bands loosely state that that 68% of data falls within the 1st band, 1 standard deviation (loosely because the empirical rule in statistics requires that distributions be normal distributions which most often stock prices are not). However if this empirical rule is from statistics where 1 standard deviation is split in half, that means that applying a 68% probability in to an entire bollinger band is wrong. ??? is this correct??

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the deviation multiples to suite your purpose, you can use 0.5 for example.